# How to test ios6 compatibility?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6

For purpose of developing app, I am having difficulty trying to find a device that's still running iOS6. Is there anyone with a smart idea?

1. I cannot rely on the iOS6 simulator because I am dependent on "Push notifications", "Camera" and "Location".
2. I cannot downgrade my iOS7 devices to iOS6 because of the "no downgrade" restriction.

Hope someone can advise.

Comment: Find an old iPod touch or old iPhone that hasn't been upgraded. Craigslist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a `iPhone 3Gs` or an `iPod Touch 4g`.  Those devices cannot be upgraded beyond 6.x versions of iOS.   As far as I know, those are the only devices that support 6.x but not 7.x.

Comment: In the end, I bought an old iPhone 3GS

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition checking

```
#define IS_IOS6 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0 && [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)   

if (IS_IOS6)
{
    NSLog(@"Running in IOS-6");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Running in IOS-7");
}
```